# Flexbox - incorrect height of element in IE

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer, video, flexbox

In this jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/VCkLy/

When we use Chrome and resize a window bringing the size of video smaller than its real width the "log" box with items always stays attached to the video's bottom, whereas in IE it does follow it when the video gets larger although when its size gets smaller than its natural width - two black bars appear above and below the video.. 
Is there anyway of removing them?

This doesn't happen if we set the "display" to either block or inline-block but because of the nature of project (this is just a simplified case) I cannot change display to anything else than "flex". Are there any CSS tweaks?

```
 #content {
  display: inline-block;
  ...
 }
```

If possible, I also would like to avoid adding JS that sets a height - it works fine in Chrome, Safari, Opera & Firefox (with a different video) just gets buggy in IE..
Thanks guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I've just found a working CSS solution, it looks like after the video is loaded IE sets a default min-height to the original video's height, but if we overwrite it with a different value in pixels, anything really small, let's say 1px - then it works fine.

```
#video {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;        
  min-height: 1px;
}
```